# Quantitative estimate of the actual electoral impact of rejected mail-in ballots in the 2020 US election?

Tags: united-states, voting, vote-by-mail

Has anyone made well-informed, quantitative estimates of the actual electoral impact of rejected mail-in ballots in the 2020 US election?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's nearly impossible to have a well-informed, quantitative estimate when so much is without precedent.  We've never had so many states trying to ramp up large scale mail-in voting at once, all on very short notice, all during a pandemic that has limited the ability of election officials to meet in person.  If the New York primary (1 in 5 mail-in ballots rejected) is an outlier and all the swing states manage to get the rejection rate down to a few percent, it could tip a close election.  If New York is a bellwether, it'll be nasty.

Comment: I've removed your answer from the question.  Feel free to post your answer as an answer.

Comment: You seem to be asking: Has anyone one made a prediction of the impact of the predicted rejected ballots in the forthcoming election; then you further qualify the prediction (of the impact) that it be "well-informed and quantitative". I also am assuming that you are targeting the presidential popular vote, as contrasted with the electoral college.

Comment: @BobE: I would be happy to see any estimate, but IMO estimates for swing states would be the most interesting. It's of little consequence whether California has a low or high number of rejected ballots.

Comment: @JoeC: Not a problem that you cut my estimate, but I wouldn't consider it a self-answer because it isn't any kind of realistic/professional estimate.

Comment: What I am pointing out is that you seem to be asking about a "well-informed and quantitative" 2nd order prediction. To address the first order (for example) 'has any well-informed" person predicted the number of ballots that will be rejected in Florida in the November 3rd popular election for president. I don't know of well-informed person or organization having done so. Then to address the 2nd order, the geographic location of the future rejected ballots would have to be surmised and correlated with the past political leanings of those locations.

Comment: (continued)  I'm not aware of anyone who has seriously ("well-informed') attempted this prognostication. However, at this time,  there may be WAGs out there, but they would likely not fit your "well-informed" criteria.

Comment: The fivethirtyeight podcast on Oct. 9, 2020 had some interesting discussion about this: https://fivethirtyeight.com/videos/the-politics-podcast-answers-your-questions-about-the-forecast/ . Silver says that this should really be considered more as a source of variability than as a systematic effect in favor of Republicans. Traditionally, political campaigns have always felt it was a big advantage to have votes banked in advance of the election, so this may counteract rejection of ballots to some extent.